# how to receive data from flask to jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to read the data from one of the flask end point to the jquery

as follows

```
<script>

      function send_response_to_the_server(client_response){
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://127.0.0.1:5001/transactions/new",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: 'json',
                headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
                data: client_response,

                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }

            });
        }

        $(function() {
           $("#generate_transaction").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/new/transaction",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
                    data:$('#transaction_form').serialize(),

                    success: function(response){
                       //setting the Amount field empty
                       document.getElementById('Amount').value = ''
                     
                     //calling the function to send the response back to the server
                     send_response_to_the_server(response);


                    },
                    error: function(error){

                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });

           });

           });

    </script>
```

Here '#generate_transaction' is the button where it get the data from the form '#transaction_form' to post back to the
url
'/new/transaction'

so in the flask app running on http://127.0.0.1:8001, i have set to return the data with additional response

```
@app.route('/new/transaction', methods=['POST'])
def generate_transaction():
    amount= request.form['Amount']
    response = {
        'Amount':amount,
        'Signature':'123'
    }
    return jsonify(response)
```

Now i want to read the above response from  '/new/transaction' to send back to other url

```
http://127.0.0.1:5001/transactions/new
```

```
 $("#generate_transaction").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://127.0.0.1:5001/transactions/new",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
                    data: ,

                    success: function(response){

                       console.log(response)


                    },
                    error: function(error){

                        console.log(error);
                    }


                });

           });
```

### Server part

```
http://127.0.0.1:5001/transactions/new
@app.route('/transactions/new', methods=['GET','POST'])
def new_transaction():
    values = request.get_json()
    value = values['Amount']
    print(value)
    response = {
        'Transaction Amount':"HI"
    }
    return "Hello IT works"
```

SO how to set the 'data' field in the above jquery to read the data from the end point '/new/transaction' from the client(running on http://127.0.0.1:8001) to the server (running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/transactions/new)?

Appreciated if anybody can help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Can anybody help on this.. ? Thanks

Comment: why not `success: function(response){
                       //setting the Amount field empty
                       document.getElementById('Amount').value = ''
                       // send the data to other url from here

                    },`

Comment: Thanks @balderman for your replay.  so how to send? Can you please explain me with the example code ..

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but you have ports `5001` and `8001` in the code up. Can you check that?

Comment: yea.. i have mentioned both part for the client and server. so client use the port 8001 and server use the port 5001. please don't mind, to avoid the conflict  i am just adding the function as you suggested  in your answer part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below

```
<script>
        function send_response_to_other_url(data) {
           // here comes code that uses $.ajax and POST to another URL
        }
        $(function() {
           $("#generate_transaction").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/new/transaction",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
                    data:$('#transaction_form').serialize(),

                    success: function(response){
                       //setting the Amount field empty
                       document.getElementById('Amount').value = ''
                       //we assume that 'response' contains the data 
                       // you want to send to another url - right?
                       send_response_to_other_url(response)
                        


                    },
                    error: function(error){

                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });

           });

           });

    </script>
```

Comment: Hi @balderman, i modified the script as suggested, but it seems that data is not posting to the second url- server: http://127.0.0.1:5001/transactions/new. i added the server.py part to recieve the response..where response return 'None'

Comment: where is the js code that sends the data to the second url?

Comment: oh i had updated on your answer..seems it was not approved.. Let me add it my question itself

Comment: Your code does not call `send_response_to_the_server` - isnt it?

Comment: sorry i missed to add  that part  here.. i updated the js code. can you please look?

Comment: What happens when you run it? If you are not sure add debug messages (`console.log(msg);`) and try to understand what is going on,

Comment: Hi @balderman, i see the data is parsing to the server and getting response in client console - in this case..-  '"Hello IT works"' , but i see received values return 'None' in the server side.. In this case: 
~~~
"values = request.get_json()"
~~~
not sure what went wrong

Comment: In `send_response_to_the_server` print to the console what you send to the server. In the server side print `request.get_data()`

Comment: yes.. the issue was with the get_json(), which are not the right method to use here.. Thank You @balderman